# how can I delete this line in circle's radius ( Close 100 % )

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pie [ text = legend , explode =0.3] {100/Oui}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! (Talking mainly to myself: I think it is a wise decision not to include the current version of `pgf-pie` into TeXLive.) You can hack it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[None/.style={draw=none}] 
\pie [ text = legend , explode =0.3,style={None}] {100/Oui} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously one does not need a package on top of Ti*k*Z to get this result.